# Angular - AOT Compilation ng vs ngc

Tags: angular, angular-aot

What is different between **AOT with ngc and rollup**

> ngc -p tsconfig-aot.json && rollup -c rollup-config.js

https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler#aot-quickstart-source-code

and **AOT with Angular CLI**

> ng build --aot

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build

both configuration is very different, which one is better or prefer.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44642696/whats-the-relationship-and-difference-between-ng-build-and-ngc

Comment: is there anything unclear about [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46088191/2545680)?

Answer (score 6):

When you run:

```
ngc -p tsconfig-aot.json
```

Angular runs AOT compiler against your files and produces a set of compiled files. These files contain compiled factories for components and modules and are not bundled in any way. In order to be loaded into a browser they need to be bundled. And so this command:

```
rollup -c rollup-config.js
```

bundles them together into one bundle using [rollup](https://rollupjs.org/). The `&&` simply chains two commands.

When you run `ng build --aot` just as in the first case it runs AOT compiler against your files but instead of simply outputting them this compilation is part of webpack bundling process. So the output is a webpack bundle.

> which one is better or prefer.

Since the [general recommendation](https://medium.com/webpack/webpack-and-rollup-the-same-but-different-a41ad427058c#989e) is to use webpack for applications and rollup for libraries, use the first configuration if you're building a library and the second for an application.